# WebApi Facebook authentication with email address

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I want to sign my users in using their email address from Facebook.  I have configured my Facebook authentication:

```
var facebookAuthenticationOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    AppId = facebookId,
    AppSecret = facebookSecret,
    Provider = new FacebookProvider()
};
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthenticationOptions);
```

I have overridden the Facebook provider to also return the email address:

```
public class FacebookProvider : FacebookAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override Task Authenticated(FacebookAuthenticatedContext context)
    {
        var accessTokenClaim = new Claim("ExternalAccessToken", context.AccessToken, "urn:facebook:access_token");
        context.Identity.AddClaim(accessTokenClaim);
        var extraClaims = GetAdditionalFacebookClaims(accessTokenClaim);
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, extraClaims.First(k => k.Key == "email").Value.ToString()));
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Provider", context.Identity.AuthenticationType));
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)));

        var userDetail = context.User;
        var link = userDetail.Value<string>("link") ?? string.Empty;
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("link", link));
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FacebookId", userDetail.Value<string>("id")));
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private static JsonObject GetAdditionalFacebookClaims(Claim accessToken)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken.Value);
        return fb.Get("me", new { fields = new[] { "email" } }) as JsonObject;
    }
```

Everything works fine in MVC - in the `LoginOwinCallback` function, I am able to retrieve the user's email address as returned from Facebook.  I am trying to achieve the same thing in WebApi using token authentication instead of external cookies.  However, although I can see my provider adding the email claim to the response, when I call the AuthenticateAsync method in the following routine, the Email claim is not included.

```
private async Task<ExternalLoginInfo> GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()
{
    var result = await Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);

    if (result == null || result.Identity == null) return null;

    var idClaim = result.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    if (idClaim != null)
    {
        return new ExternalLoginInfo()
        {
            DefaultUserName = result.Identity.Name == null ? "" : result.Identity.Name.Replace(" ", ""),
            ExternalIdentity = result.Identity,
            Login = new UserLoginInfo(idClaim.Issuer, idClaim.Value)
        };
    }

    return null;
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else facing the same problem, the Email claim is available - just a bit hidden.

Firstly, to correctly retrieve the user's email address from Facebook, the authentication set-up in the ConfigureAuth method of Startup.Auth.cs should be:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    AppId = facebookId,
    AppSecret = facebookSecret,
    Scope= {"email"},
    UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=email"
});
```

In the LoginOwinCallback method of the MVC AccountController class, the email address is found in the Email property of the ExternalLoginInfo object returned by `var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();`.

To retrieve the email address in the WebAPI AccountController class, you will need to cast the `User.Identity` object to the `ClaimsIdentity` type.

```
[OverrideAuthentication]
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("ExternalLogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
{
    if (error != null)
    {
        return Redirect(Url.Content("~/") + "#error=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(error));
    }

    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
    }

    // get all of the claims
    var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;  // this cast exposes all of the claims returned by Facebook

    // get the external login details
    var externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(claimsIdentity);

    if (externalLogin == null)
    {
        return InternalServerError();
    }

    if (externalLogin.LoginProvider != provider)
    {
           AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
    }

    var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(new UserLoginInfo(externalLogin.LoginProvider,
            externalLogin.ProviderKey));

    var hasRegistered = user != null;

    if (hasRegistered)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        var oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
            OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        var cookieIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        var properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);
    }
    else
    {
        var claims = claimsIdentity?.Claims ?? externalLogin.GetClaims();
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

This means you can then use the `FindFirst` method on the Identity to find the email claim returned by Facebook.